# How does the short key to open a referenced function work in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, I move cursor to the function I'm interested in,

then press `^W`,

then press `gf`.

It'll automatically open the referenced function.

How does it work?

Comment: Probably just ordinary magic.

Comment: @KAK,what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it was a joke. I was remembering a quote from Arthur C. Clarke: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Answer (score 1):

`:he CTRL-W_gf` says it will open file under cursor in new tab.

If it does something else try `:verbose nmap <C-w>gf` to see if there is a mapping which does anything else.